# Victory native charts not working with create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, reactjs-native, create-react-native-app

**I'm new to react-native and want to use victory-native in my create-react-native-app. I came across Victory charts after googling for some time, but unfortunately, I'm not able to use it.**  [This is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVrgR.jpg)  And [image: Android Error log Screenshot]

And this my code:

```
import React from 'react';  
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';  
import { VictoryBar, VictoryChart } from 'victory-native';  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
  container: {  
    flex: 1,  
  },  
});  

const data = [
    { quarter: 1, earnings: 13000 },
    { quarter: 2, earnings: 16500 },
    { quarter: 3, earnings: 14250 },
    { quarter: 4, earnings: 19000 },
];

const AppChart = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VictoryChart>
        <VictoryBar
          style={{
            data: { fill: 'blue' },
          }}
          data={data}
          x="quarter"
          y="earnings"
        />
      </VictoryChart>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AppChart;
```

Comment: How does your android monitor Logs look like ?

Comment: I'm added android monitor logs with the question.

Comment: It seems to be working for me. `react-native: 0.42, victory-native:0.7.0`. What are the versions of the libraries that you are using ? Maybe try in a new react native project.